# Как осуществить редактирование данных в массиве структур

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Bus_Info
{
   char b_n[9];
   char name[15];
   char way[4];
   int parking;
   int lesion;
} bus_Info;

int sf (const void *a, const void *b) {
  return strcmp (((bus_Info*)a)->b_n, ((bus_Info*)b)->b_n);
}

int main()
{  //char mass[100];
                   //переменная для меню
   int n,str;
   char c[40], c1[4];
   FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Bus_Info.dat","r");
   if (fp==NULL)
   {printf("Its impossible to open"); return 1;}
    str=0;
    while (! feof(fp))         // цикл подсчета строк в файле базы данных
        if (fgetc(fp)=='\n') str=str+1;
    //printf("%d\n",str);
    fclose(fp);                //важно закрыть и открыть файл заново или поставить указатель на начало файла данных
     bus_Info * mass;
     mass = (bus_Info*) malloc(str*sizeof(bus_Info));
    fp = fopen("Bus_Info.dat","r");
    if (fp==NULL)
       {printf("Its impossible to open"); return 1;}
    for (n=0; n<str; n++)
    {
        fgets(c,40,fp);
        strncpy ( mass[n].b_n, c, 8);
        mass[n].b_n[8]='\0';
        strncpy ( mass[n].name, c+8, 15 );
        mass[n].name[14]='\0';
        strncpy ( mass[n].way, c+23, 4 );
        mass[n].way[3]='\0';
        strncpy ( c1, c+27, 1 );
        c1[1]='\0';
        mass[n].parking=atoi(c1);
        strncpy ( c1, c+29, 3 );
        c1[2]='\0';
        mass[n].lesion=atoi(c1);
    }
    fclose(fp);

        for (n=0; n<str; n++)
        {
            printf("\n%s\n",mass[n].b_n);
            printf("%s\n",mass[n].name);
            printf("%s\n",mass[n].way);
            printf("%d\n",mass[n].parking);
            printf("%d\n",mass[n].lesion);
        };



        free(mass);

    return 0;
}
```

Нужно реализовать: добавление, удаление и редактирование элемента. Но под массив уже выделена память `mass = (bus_Info*) malloc(str*sizeof(bus_Info));` Тоисть нам нужно каждый раз его переносить в какой-то временный массив и переопределять память при добавлении/удалении элемента или есть более элегантный способ.

Comment: Стандартные контейнеры не разрешены на задаче? И про c++ тут что-то не очень много.

Comment: Нет. без контейнеров грустно.

Comment: Вы можете воспользоватся стороними библиотеками для работы с различными типами данных (GLib). Но если Вы хотите создать свою систему . То алгорит достаточно прост. Выделяете память на N элементов заполняете по мере необходимости. Если нужно увеличиваете в два раза N*2. Копируете элементы в новый массив. И продолжаете дальше работать . Все контейнеры работаю по этому принципу.

Comment: @Yaroslav если не затруднит, приведите фрагмент рабочего кода в ответе, что бы было визуально понятней как это всё происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамический массив пишется несложно. По часам - примерно 8-10 минут :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Data_ {
    int x,y,z;
    // ...
} Data;

typedef struct Array_ {
    Data * data;
    int    size;
    int    reserved;
} Array;

Array* makeArray(int startSize)
{
    Array * a = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    a->data = malloc(sizeof(Data)*startSize);
    a->reserved = startSize;
    a->size = 0;
    return a;
};

void killArray(Array * a)
{
    free(a->data);
    free(a);
}


Data * getData(Array* a)
{
    return a->data;
}

int sizeData(Array* a)
{
    return a->size;
}

void addData(Array* a, Data d)
{
    if (a->size == a->reserved) // Full
    {
        a->data = realloc(a->data,sizeof(Data)*a->reserved*2);
        a->reserved *= 2;
    }
    a->data[a->size++] = d;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    Array * a = makeArray(2);
    for(i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        Data d;
        d.x = i;
        d.y = 2*i;
        d.z = 3*i;
        addData(a,d);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < sizeData(a); ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d %3d %3d\n",getData(a)[i].x,getData(a)[i].y,getData(a)[i].z);
    }

    killArray(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Выложен [тут](http://ideone.com/gxuyBj).

Ну, понятно, что нужны всяческие проверки на ошибки...

Answer (score 1):

На примере массива uint16_t Но здесь может быть указатель на любой тип. Но это тока набросок без различных проверок.

```
uint16_t * array = NULL;
uint32_t amount = 10;
uint32_t count = 0;

void init(void)
{
  array = malloc(sizeof(uin16_t) * amount);
}

void deinit(void)
{
  free(array);
} 

void reinit(void)
{
 uint16_t * t;
 uint32_t old_amount = amount;
 amount <<= 1;
 t = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t) * amount); 
 memmove(t,array,old_amount);
 free(array);
 array = t;
}

void add(uint16_t element)
{
 uint16_t * begin = array;
 begin += count;
 *begin = element;
 count ++;
 if(count == amount ){
    reinit();
 }
}

void change(uint32_t number,uint16 element)
{
 uint16_t * begin = array;
 begin += number;
 *begin = element;
} 

void del(uint32_t number)
{
 uint16_t * begin = array;
 uin16_t * end = array;
 begin += number;
 end += (number + 1);
 memmove(begin,end,(count - number));
 count --;
} 

uint16_t get_element(uint32_t number)
{
 uint16_t * begin = array;
 begin += number;
 return *begin;
}
```